# API: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get the results for the term: 'german' from an api..

Unfortunately, I get error:
'**Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token**'.

I see that there are html characters in middle dots in the `overview` response..
and there are lots of `\"` (it should escape the quates).

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'testing',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
        console.dir(json);
    },
    error: function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
});
```

This is my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mrLkyx7j/

Thanks.

Comment: just replace your datatype jsonp to only json

Comment: try with $.get('your_url');

Comment: but I need it cross origin, otherwise I get: "Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: url,
jsonpCallback: 'testing',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(json) {
    console.log(json);
},
error: function(e) {
    console.log(e.message);
}
});
```

Comment: It would have been nice to comment on what you are doing not just putting code there :)